# Shopify Order Status using Admin API

Tags: api, shopify

I need to get status of order using Shopify API. I know the payload and I am able to get the order response but wanted to know the logic to get the status line of the order if some have that handy.

Like I get fulfillment status, payment status, confirmed status, processing_method, cancelled_at so using all these and other attributes, I want to frame a line which will give the end user the complete status.

Like e.g., "your order is confirmed and is ready to ship, it will reach to you by next week. Thanks"

any help?

Answer (score 2):

The example message that you shared will be a result of several Shopify API resources combined. To iterate step by setp, you will need to use the following 3 API resources.

1. [Order](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order)
2. [Fulfillment](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/shipping-and-fulfillment/fulfillment)
3. [Fulfillment Event](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/shipping-and-fulfillment/fulfillmentevent)

First from the Order resource, have look at *fulfillment_status* field. Valid values are

- shipped: Show orders that have been shipped.
- partial: Show partially shipped orders.
- unshipped: Show orders that have not yet been shipped

From the Fulfillment resource, have look at *status* and *shipment_status* fields.

From the FulfillmentEvent resource, have look at *estimated_delivery_at* and *status* field.

Combined these fields together, you have the information if any of the items are fulfilled, shipment status and estimated delivery date.

You can have a look at code inside Shopify Email templates that are sent on Shipping Confirmation etc.

Sample Code from Shipping Confirmation Email

```
{% if fulfillment.item_count == item_count %} 
  {% capture email_title %}Your order is on the way{% endcapture %}
  {% capture email_body %}Your order is on the way. Track your shipment to see the delivery status.{% endcapture %}
{% elsif fulfillment.item_count > 1 %} 
  {% if fulfillment_status == 'fulfilled' %}
    {% capture email_title %}The last items in your order are on the way{% endcapture %}
    {% capture email_body %}The last items in your order are on the way. Track your shipment to see the delivery status.{% endcapture %}
  {% else %}
    {% capture email_title %}Some items in your order are on the way{% endcapture %}
    {% capture email_body %}Some items in your order are on the way. Track your shipment to see the delivery status.{% endcapture %}
  {% endif %}
{% else %} 
  {% if fulfillment_status == 'fulfilled' %}
    {% capture email_title %}The last item in your order is on the way{% endcapture %}
    {% capture email_body %}The last item in your order is on the way. Track your shipment to see the delivery status.{% endcapture %}
  {% else %}
    {% capture email_title %}One item in your order is on the way{% endcapture %}
    {% capture email_body %}One item in your order is on the way. Track your shipment to see the delivery status.{% endcapture %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% capture email_emphasis %}Estimated delivery date: <strong>{{fulfillment.estimated_delivery_at | date: "%B %-d, %Y"}}</strong>{% endcapture %}
```

Comment: thats great, thanks. I am planning to use voice, so it should first check if the order is cancelled or not, if not cancelled, then if the order is confirmed and payment is done , if everything is fine, then shipment..

so do you have this complete if else scenarios? this will help in creating a string with complete order informations.

I can create the string, but wanted to check if someone has it handy so that i can reuse it after some customization. also it may happen, while i start, i miss some scenarios , so dont want to miss any. 

thanks again.